# Example(s) of "A subscript ([ ]) expression that does not evaluate to an array" in C

Tags: c

I think I have never seen a [] that doesn't mean array in C.

Background:
I was reading about l-values and r-values here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bkbs2cds.aspx and there it says so. I am curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it says there is "A subscript ([ ]) expression that does not evaluate to an array."  The key words here are "evaluate to."

If you have an array of int called `x`, the expression `x[5]` evaluates to an int, not an array.  On the other hand, if it's an array of arrays of int, the expression `x[5]` evaluates to an array of int, and therefore is can't be a valid l-value.

Comment: +1. Since you are here, what is an incomplete type?

Comment: @AnubhavSaini: A quick Google search turns up http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/200xfxh6.aspx which explains it better than I could.

Comment: not being lazy. Suspected the structure though. Thanks.